# Spark fails with ClassNotFoundException for SerializedLambda

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm learning spark and my first program is a words counter and I have had problems executing the program in standalone mode

When I execute the code in local mode, I have no problems (`setMaster("local")`) but When I try to execute in standalone (with a master-slave) , It doesn't finish (I have run the script ./sbin/start-all.sh). The program runs. but collecting data, a exceptions happens. (in the line `counter.collectAsMap()` )

The error is the following:

```
15/01/30 15:23:54 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, ******): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.f$3 of type org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction in instance of org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1
```

and the code is the following:

```
public class MainTest {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws {
        String origin = "originPath";

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("org.sparkexample.WordCount").setMaster("spark://localhost:7077");
        JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaRDD<String> file = context.textFile(origin);
        JavaRDD<String> words = file.flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")));
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pairs = words.mapToPair(word ->new Tuple2<>(word,1));
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counter = pairs.reduceByKey(( valueA,valueB) ->valueA +valueB);
        Map<String,Integer> map = counter.collectAsMap();
        map.forEach((key,value)->System.out.println(key+"="+value));
    }
}
```

My machine has Oracle Java 8 installed and I launch the master and one slave with ./sbin/start-all.sh script

Which one can be the error?

UPDATE:

I'm trying a Java 7 Implementation and I have other problem: The exception is:

```
15/01/30 12:47:21 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, ***): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.c4om.l3p3.sparkTest.MainTest
```

Maybe this is a configuration problem?

The Java7 Code is the following:

```
public static void countWordsJava7(String path,Boolean local, Boolean printResult){
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("org.sparkexample.WordCount").setMaster("spark://localhost:7077");
    JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> file = context.textFile(path);
    JavaRDD<String> words = file.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<String> call(String s) {
            return Arrays.asList(" ".split(s));
        }
    });
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pairs = words.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
            return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
        }
    });
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counter = pairs.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
            return i1 + i2;
        }
    });
    Map<String, Integer> map = counter.collectAsMap();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClassNotFoundException` means a class is missing on the workers. There can be different reasons, depending on what class it is complaining about:

- **It's a class from your own package.** You have not deployed the jar file with your code to the workers. You can use `SparkConf.setJars` to have Spark distribute your jar for you.
- **It's a system class.** This suggests the workers are running with a different version of Java than the application. For example  `java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda` is a Java 8 class — if it's missing, your workers are running Java 7.
- **It's a library class.** You need to install the library on all workers, or use `SparkConf.setJars` to have Spark distribute your jar for you.

To debug this sort of problem, print the classpath on the workers.

```
rdd.foreachPartition { p => println(System.getProperty("java.class.path")) }
```

Comment: and Which one is the jar for java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm totally wrong. Didn't read the exception carefully enough. Now I think rather that your workers do not have Java 8.

Comment: I thought about that but my machine has Java 8 and I launch the master and slave with the official script, I have update the question. Also, I have no problem with other Java 8 expressions like reduceByKey function

Comment: You may still have Java 7 installed as well, and accidentally run the workers on that. I know it's a bit of a stretch... I wouldn't conclude anything from `reduceByKey` working though. At that point nothing has been sent to the worker yet. Only the `collect` call causes the previous operations to be executed.

Comment: Something has installed OpenJDK 7 in my computer... repositories or something... :(. I go to purge OpenJDK and install again... Thanks, I will try and then accept your solution

Comment: The problem persists, and now I have two implementations, Java 7/8, the error for Java 7 is ClassNotFoundException for my class MainTest. the error in Java 8 the error has change (see the question). Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Yeah, now it sounds like what I assumed was the case in my first answer :). Sounds like your own class file is not on the classpath of the workers. Use `SparkConf.setJars`. I've updated the answer to try to cover everything.

Comment: A lot of thanks!!! The first problem was the JDK and the second is that I have code with lambda (I do not execute it).

Comment: @fhuertas can you elaborate on what you mean with "second is that I have code with lambda (I do not execute it)"?

Comment: I don't remember but I think that the problem was with Java version (Java 7 and  lambda)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error `cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda` if I run code from IDE like Idea, and invoke setJars(new String[]{"/path/to/jar/with/your/class.jar"}) on SparkConf instance, then it worked.

For example:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("LineCount");
conf.setMaster("spark://localhost:7077")
conf.setJars(new String[] { "/home/path/MainTest.jar" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set jar path on the SparkConf then it works. jar path is the path of jar file after compile by maven or ant.

```
String master = "spark://localhost:7077";
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName(WordCountTask.class.getName())
            .setMaster(master)
            .setJars(new String[]{"/home/user/Projects/spark-test/target/first-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"})
```

Hope it help.